# Incorrect calculation of reputation

Tags: bug, reputation

A few days back, my reputation was suddenly reduced by about 50 without any log in my reputation tab (like user remove, question removed, unaccept, ...), this was the second time this was happening to me (the first one was a very long time ago).

I thought maybe there is some other reason (just like user removed) that is not being monitored or maybe there was a miscalculation in my reputation and a recalculation has corrected it. however, it was not a big deal.

Today I came accros a user profile that as he has not much questions and answers, it was very easy to calculate his reputation. and there was an obvious miscalculation.

here is the user profile link:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/6313502/chrisr

lets calculate his rep:

```
1     (initial rep)
12    (6 accepted answer for his questions) 
5     (1 upvote for one of his questions)
15    (has 1 accepted answer)
      (no downvotes neither for questions nor for answers)
--------------------------------------------
33
```

He should have a reputation of 33 while his reputation is only 19.

Is there anything that I'm missing, or really there is a miscalculation in reputation?

Comment: Try clicking on "show removed posts" in your reputation history so you see reputation changes resulting from post deletions/undeletions.

Comment: The accepted answer in your example is the OP accepting their own answer.  No rep for that.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Stephen Rauch is right, if you get rid of +15 because self-accept, it would be right.

Comment: @U9-Forward yes I knew that, but I didn't saw that, however still 33 - 15 = 18

Answer (score 1):

For reference:

[image: 1+5+10-2+2-5+2+2+2+2 = 19]

You can go through and expand all those arrows. By my reckoning:

- The +2s and the +4 are all from accepting someone else's answer. (Accepting 5 answers = 10)
- The -5 on September 1 is a user who was removed, which removed an upvote.
- The +8 on July 11 was two question upvotes and a question downvoted.
- The +5 on July 1 was a question upvote.

So 10 - 5 + 8 + 5 + 1 for the initial reputation = 19.